# MongoDb sum issue after match and group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have document as userDetails:

```json
[
  {
        "roles": [
            "author",
            "reader"
        ],
        "completed_roles": ["author", "reader"],
        "address": {
            "current_address": {
                "city": "abc"
            }
        },
        "is_verified": true
    },

    {
        "roles": [
            "reader"
        ],
        "completed_roles": ["reader"],
        "address": {
            "current_address": {
                "city": "abc"
            }
        },
        "is_verified": true
    },
    {
        "roles": [
            "author"
        ],
        "completed_roles": [],
        "address": {
            "current_address": {
                "city": "xyz"
            }
        },
        "is_verified": false
    }
]
```

I want to fetch sum for all roles which has author based on city, total_roles_completed and is_verified.

So the O/P should look like:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "city": "abc"
    },
    "total_author": 1,
    "total_roles_completed": 1,
    "is_verified": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "city": "xyz"
    },
    "total_author": 1,
    "total_roles_completed": 0,
    "is_verified": 0
  }
]
```

Basic O/P required:

- Filter the document based on author in role (other roles may be present in role but author must be present)
- Sum the author based on city
- sum on basis of completed_profile has "author"
- Sum on basis of documents if they are verified.

For this I tried as:

```
db.userDetails.aggregate([ 
    {
        $match: {
            roles: {
                $eleMatch: {
                    $eq: "author"
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $unwind: "$completed_roles"
    },  
    { 
        "$group": { 
            _id: { city: "$address.current_address.city"},             
            total_authors: {$sum: 1},
            total_roles_completed: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        {
                            $eq: ["$completed_roles","author"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            is_verified: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        {
                            $eq: ["$is_verified",true]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }  
    }
]);
```

But the sum is incorrect. Please let me know where I made mistake. Also, if anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Edit: I figured that because of unwind it is giving me incorrect value, if I remove the unwind the sum is coming correct.

Is there any other way by which I can calculate the sum of total_roles_completed for each city?

Comment: your document examples seems not correct , maybe current_address need to be in {}?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can try this query:

- First `$match` to get only documents where `roles` contains `author`.
- And then `$group` by the city (the document is not a valid JSON so I assume is `address:{"current_addres:{city:"abc"}}`). This `$group` get the authors for each city and also: `$sum` 1 if "author" is in `completed_roles` and check if is verified.

Here I don't know the way to know if the author is verified (I don't know if can be true in one document and false in other document. If is the same value over all documents you can use `$first` to get the first `is_verified` value). But I decided to use `$allElementsTrue` in a `$project` stage, so this only will be true if `is_verified` is true in all documents grouped by `$group`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "roles": "author"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$address.current_address.city",
      "total_author": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "total_roles_completed": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$in": [
                "author",
                "$completed_roles"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "is_verified": {
        "$addToSet": "$is_verified"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "city": "$_id",
      "is_verified": {
        "$allElementsTrue": "$is_verified"
      },
      "total_author": 1,
      "total_roles_completed": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3EvOf2Byaaa)

The result from this query is:

```
[
  {
    "city": "xyz",
    "is_verified": false,
    "total_author": 1,
    "total_roles_completed": 0
  },
  {
    "city": "abc",
    "is_verified": true,
    "total_author": 2,
    "total_roles_completed": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Wonderful query! A very little misunderstanding is that OP wanted the sum of verified users inside is_verified and not a boolean (if all users are verified or not).